# Rails: Scoping from an instance via the child model's other parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I know the question title is a little convoluted, so I'll do my best to explain.

```
A venue can have many newsitems.

A newsitem belongs to a newsitem_category and a venue.

A newsitem_category can have many newsitems.
```

So when I select a venue that has many news items, I want to group that query by the newsitem_category.

## I am trying to list all newsitems associated with a venue by their category

Desired output is something like this....

```
Venue.where(id: 24).first.newsitems_by_category 
=> {fishing: [id: 1 .......],
    other_categories: [id: 4 ......]
   }
```

Currently I have a scope in my newsitem category model like this

```
  CATEGORIES = ['foo', 'bar' .....]
  scope :categories, -> { (where(title: CATEGORIES))}
```

Which I merge in the news item model

```
    scope :news_categories_scope, -> { joins(:newsitem_cat).merge(NewsitemCat.categories) }
```

But obviously this doesn't take into account the venue, and this is where I am having difficulty. Scoping on the instance of a venue, not the model itself.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: well, see my desired output, List all newsitems associated with a venue by their category

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007fad599e2600> 

surely we should start from the venue model?

Comment: Did you try: `NewsitemCat.joins(newsitems: :venue).where(venue: { id: 24 }).categories`? Also, which version of Rails and Ruby are you using?

Comment: rails 4. this is closer,     newsitems.where(newsitem_cat_id: NewsitemCat.categories), except the results aren't yet in a hash

Comment: You're confusing me here, what do you want? newsitem categories or newsitems?

Comment: see the desired output, it cant be clearer than that surely?

Comment: i want news items grouped by their categories

Comment: Make sure you have:`belongs_to :venue` in `Newsitem` model class. and then try: `Newsitem.joins(:newsitem_category, :venue).merge(NewsitemCat.categories).where(venue: {id: 24})`